# Failed to validate Access Token with oidc-client-js and Apereo CAS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cas, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm trying to login with [Apereo CAS 5.1.1](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) in my react application using OIDC. Looking for libraries to achieve this, I landed on [oidc-client-js 1.7.0](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js), but I'm encountering the following error:

> ResponseValidator._validateAccessToken: Failed to validate at_hash dWr5-bD5lv8C1x3VcfFn1Q dWr5+bD5lv8C1x3VcfFn1Q==

Following the trace, I found where the exception is thrown

```
var a = s.substr(0, s.length / 2), u = this._joseUtil.hexToBase64Url(a);

return u !== e.profile.at_hash ? 
(i.Log.error("ResponseValidator._validateAccessToken: Failed to validate at_hash", u, e.profile.at_hash), Promise.reject(new Error("Failed to validate at_hash"))) : 
(i.Log.debug("ResponseValidator._validateAccessToken: success"), Promise.resolve(e));
```

The problem is that `this._joseUtil.hexToBase64Url(a)` doesn't add padding (`=`) and in this particular case the `+` sign. That's because those characters aren't accepted in an URL. So, the comparison always (or almost always) will be false. For example, in this execution:

```
dWr5-bD5lv8C1x3VcfFn1Q != dWr5+bD5lv8C1x3VcfFn1Q==
```

On the other hand, I think there's something I'm missing or misconfigured in my application, because otherwise every person using this library will encounter the same issue.

So, my question is: How can I successfully validate the access token in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem going through the code of both pieces of code interacting to perform the validation.

It turned out that CAS version I was using (5.1.1) has an error in the creation of the access token hash `at_hash` value.

The class `org.apereo.cas.oidc.token.OidcIdTokenGeneratorService` has the following method: `generateAccessTokenHash`. The last lines of code where it actually generates the hash are:

```
final byte[] digested = DigestUtils.rawDigest(hashAlg, tokenBytes);
final byte[] hashBytesLeftHalf = Arrays.copyOf(digested, digested.length / 2);
return EncodingUtils.encodeBase64(hashBytesLeftHalf);
```

The problem is that it encodes to base64 when the `at_hash` should be encoded in base64url according to [this](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660):

> Access Token hash value. Its value is the base64url encoding of the
>   left-most half of the hash of the octets of the ASCII representation
>   of the access_token value, where the hash algorithm used is the hash
>   algorithm used in the alg Header Parameter of the ID Token's JOSE
>   Header. For instance, if the alg is RS256, hash the access_token value
>   with SHA-256, then take the left-most 128 bits and base64url encode
>   them. The at_hash value is a case sensitive string.

This problem was solved in following version of CAS, at least I can confirm that 5.2.x solved it by changing (among other things) the last line to:

```
return EncodingUtils.encodeUrlSafeBase64(hashBytesLeftHalf);
```

I hope this could be helpful to anybody who faces the same issue.